# Добавить активный класс и убрать у предыдущего на чистом Javascript

Tags: javascript

понимаю что это где то было, поиск не дает решения на чистом JS

Есть несколько блоков слайдов и кнопки вперед и назад.

Первый слайд с классов active 
при клике на кнопку нужно убрать класс у активного элемента и поставить следующему, и нужно чтобы так работало на всех следующих слайдах до конца. и обратный функционал на кнопку назад

вот код

```
  <div class="why">
    <div class="why__slide why__slide-active"></div>
    <div class="why__slide "></div>
    <div class="why__slide "></div>
    <div class="why__slide "></div>
    <div class="why__slide "></div>
    <button class="why__button-left" id="why-left-button">назад</button>
    <button class="why__button-right" id="why-right-button">вперед</button>  
   </div>
```

пожалуйста объясните подробнее по действиям как нужно поступить, потому что представленные варианты ответа еще больше запутали

У меня получается только удалить класс у активного элемента, и поставить следующему, но дальше на 3 и 4 блок действия не работают

вот то что я написал:

```
whyPageRightButton.addEventListener('click', moveRight);

function moveRight(){
    let slides = document.getElementsByClassName('why__slide');
    let index = 0;

    slides[index].classList.remove('why__slide-active');
    slides[++index].classList.add('why__slide-active');
    index = index+1;
}
```

Большое спасибо, заработало!

```
         let slides = document.getElementsByClassName('why__slide');
         let slideActive = document.querySelector('.why__slide-active');
         let index = 0;

    whyPageRightButton.addEventListener('click', moveRight);

    function moveRight(){


    slides[index].classList.remove('why__slide-active');
    slides[++index].classList.add('why__slide-active');

    }

    whyPageLeftButton.addEventListener('click', moveLeft);

    function moveLeft(){


    slides[index].classList.remove('why__slide-active');
    slides[index-1].classList.add('why__slide-active');

    }
```

Теперь при клике на кнопку вправо удаляется класс у активного дива и добавляется к следующему за ним. НО когда он доходит до последнего , как сделать чтобы он останавливался и больше ничего не менял?

И я попытался реализовать движение по клику назад, но у меня таким образом перемещение идет только на один див назад, я понимаю что ошибка в том что 
index равен 0 , но не совсем понимаю как сделать так чтобы индекс был общим у двух функций и они изменяли его для перемещения

Большое спасибо за помощь.

Что я делаю не так?

```
    whyPageRightButton.addEventListener('click', moveRight);

    function moveRight(){
        if (slides[index] != slides.length - 1 ) {
           slides[index].classList.remove('why__slide-active');
           slides[++index].classList.add('why__slide-active');

        }
        else {
              slides[0].classList.add('why__slide-active');

        }
       }
```

Comment: `let slides = document.getElementsByClassName('why__slide');` можно делать один раз **до** функции `moveRight`. Плюс из этой же функции нужно вынести объявление `index` иначе каждый раз при заходе в эту функцию он переопределяется и его значения только 0,1,2

Comment: Ну и, например в моем ответе, подход немного другой: хранится не список всех объектов, а только список объектов с классом `active`. В этом случае в коллекции у тебя всегда 1 элемент. ты его берешь, снимаешь с него active, и  устанавливаешь следующему элементу

Comment: я обновил вопрос, подскажи пожалуйста куда двигаться дальше?

Comment: _чтобы он останавливался и больше ничего не менял?_ - просто нужно внутрь функции добавить условие - если index >= max-1 - ничего не делать, и аналогично со второй функцией, только проверка с 0, если Index == 0  ничего не делаем. Плюс во второй функции `moveLeft` не меняется сам `index`, в отличии от первой, где есть вызов `++index`. Хотя на мой взгляд лучше сделать явный инкремент и декремент

Comment: Прошу пожалуйста подкорректировать код

Comment: вот тут ты сравниваешь элемент массива с максимальным индексом `if (slides[index] != slides.length - 1 ) {` а должен сравнивать index

Comment: прости меня, кажется я совсем тупой =)